# TexStudio Dark Background Theme with Custom Font Size

Tags: texstudio, themes

I located and edited my texstudio.ini file to include the following text under the [formats] heading. This gives me a dark theme that is easier on the eyes than the default white background.

My only issue is I can no longer go into the TexStudio preferences and change the font size to something larger than 11. I suppose this code shown below is overwriting any global preferences by TexStudio. What part of the code below do I change to make my font 14?

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#839496
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\bold=false
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\background=#002b36
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\foreground=#6c71c4
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#586e75
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#cb4b16
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#859900
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#268bd2
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\bold=false
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#dc322f
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\sweave\priority=-1
data\sweave\bold=false
data\sweave\italic=false
data\sweave\overline=false
data\sweave\underline=false
data\sweave\strikeout=false
data\sweave\waveUnderline=false
data\sweave\fontFamily=
data\sweave\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\foreground=#c93682
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\foreground=#2aa198
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#399900
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\bold=false
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#b58900
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\bold=false
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\background=#073642
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\pointSize=0
```

Comment: Which version of TeXstudio under which operating system? What `Font Family` did you set for the editor?

Comment: Why not just CTRL+MouseWheel (to zomm) to adjust the font size?
If I check my settings, all font sizes are in percent.
Ah, for the Editor: add this to your txsprofile-file: `[texmaker]
X11\Font%20Size=14`.

Comment: @gilu `X11\Font%20Size=14` overrides the default font size for X11 server environment, i.e. sets the size of the text used outside the editor window. For the editor window, what the OP is after, the setting is `Editor\Font%20Size=14`. But the Q is why can't it be set from the settings (because I can using the theme code above).

Comment: @alwaysask, you're right about settings. Its `Editor\Font%20Size=10` in `[texmaker]`.
But why change the settings if you can CTRL+Scroll to the font size you like? My guess is, the OP cannot access the settings becaus of some corrupted data/file(s)?!
BTW: I thought if you change the X11 to 14 and all other fonts are at 100%, then all fonts are 14 ;).

Comment: CTRL+MouseWheel does work. I didn't know that. Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use as well? Sometimes I'm on my laptop with only a trackpad. I tried CTRL++ and that works but only on the pdf view of the document.

Comment: @sixsigmar, CTRL++ works fine (TeXstudio 2.11.0). Funny thing is, I can't zoom in or out in pdf viewer (only when windowed) with CTRL++.